# Data Migration from Oracle to Mongo DB

Tags: oracle, mongodb, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-migration

I am currently doing a POC for my project to see if I can migrate to MongoDB from Oracle . My Oracle structure is currently flat ( Single table with no relational tables with a few columns and a CLOB ) .

I have about 10 lac records and want to migrate this to Mongo to analyse the performance of my retrievals/ other queries that exist currently .

I could write some custom script to move this from Oracle to Mongo but i was wondering if there are any free tools out there which could help me move all the rows from oracle and store it as json documents in mongo ( Column name : data ) .

So are there any tools out there which could help me out ??

P.S : I did see pelica migrator but it supports only ten documents in the trial version :(

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "MongoImport" tool?