# Data Reconciliation after migration from oracle to MongoDB

Tags: java, python, oracle, mongodb

For our project we are migrating data from Oracle to MongoDB with records running into millions now after migration (which is done via flatfiles and shell scripts by Dev team) now as a QA team we are expected to validate these records for confirmation with source in the sense we need to ensure that the migrated records should be exactly same as the source data.
We had developed a Java program to bring data from Oracle DB and Mongo DB and compare it locally using CSVs as below:

```
 /************ Fetch Mongo DB data ***********/
      MongoClientURI connectionString = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017");
      MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
      MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
      MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("books");
      MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();
     // MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().projection(Projections.exclude("_idoid")).iterator();
      try {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            JFlat flatMe = new JFlat(cursor.next().toJson());
              flatMe
                  .json2Sheet()
                  .headerSeparator("")
                  .write2csv("C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Desktop\\MongoTargettest.csv");
          }
      } finally {
          cursor.close();
      } 
      mongoClient.close();
```

Referred [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305131/export-from-oracle-to-mongodb-using-python) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318178/data-migration-from-oracle-to-mongo-db) but could not come to conclusion how to validate the migrated records, can someone please suggest few approaches

Comment: May be you can copy the result of Oracle and MongoDB in 2 dofferent sheet of Excel and do a vlookup.

Comment: @XING: the volume is huge running into millions sometimes billions of records